# Which algorithms can be expressed with mostly set intersections

Tags: classification

I'm sorry in advance if my question is too broad of does not fit here.
Which algorithms in machine learning classification and data mining can be expressed entirely or almost entirely as set intersection operations. 
For example, for the case of machine learning classification I do not care about how those sets are computed, I am only interested in the classification algorithm being mostly set intersection operations.

Imagine you have a trained model $M$ for some binary classification task, a threshold $t$, and you are given a sample $s$.
In the simplest case: Are there classifiers which work by outputting 1 iff $\vert M \cap SomeProcessingFunction(s) \vert > t$.
I am also interested in classification algorithms which consist out of multiple set intersection operations.

The rough motivation behind it as follows:
I have a (theoretical) model, where (during the classification) set intersection operations of data sets are cheap, when compared to any other type of instructions.
I am looking for machine learning classification algorithms, which would be particularly efficient in such a model.

thanks in advance!

Comment: If you could describe better what you exactly mean - possibly with an example - one might be able to help before this question is closed due to beeing too broad/ unclear

Comment: All classifiers are doing what you want (just it is often express in a more analytic way) , the affectation of a new element in a class is not the issue in terms of performance, it is training the model that costs ..

Answer (score 1):

How about 2-class K-nearest neighbors, where SomeProcessingFunction is to compute the K nearest neighbors, M is just the set of positive training samples, and $t$ is K/2?

Comment: Nailed it! It's very hard to think of any other algorithm that fits nearly as well.

Comment: I know! I decided to quit while I was ahead.